# Why string.matches("^[A-Z0-9\\-\\_]+") not working when i am giving value of string by manipulating another string,

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String aStr="TEST-1-TV_50";
System.out.println(aStr.matches("^[A-Z0-9\\-\\_]+")); //TRUE.
```

But why this is not working..?

```
String aStr1= "$local:TEST12-1-TV_50 as xs:boolean";

int strtIndex=aStr.indexOf(":");
int endIndex=aStr.indexOf("as");

String extractedStr=aStr1.substring(strtIndex+1,endIndex);  //TEST12-1-TV_50


System.out.println(extractedStr.matches("^[A-Z0-9\\-\\_]+")); //FALSE.
```

Why its giving result as false.???

Answer (score 4):

There's a trailing space in `extractedStr`.

So it contains `"TEST12-1-TV_50 "` (not that there's a space after the final 0).

You can either replace `endIndex` with `aStr.indexOf(" as")` (starting space) or simply call `trim()` on `extractedStr`:

```
String extractedStr=aStr1.substring(strtIndex+1,endIndex).trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include space also in character class:

```
extractedStr.matches("^[A-Z0-9 _-]+"); // true
```

OR else call `trim()` before `matches`

```
extractedStr.trim().matches("^[A-Z0-9_-]+"); // true
```

**PS:** You don't need to escape `_` in character class and hyphen as well (if used at start or end)

Comment: Great to know, if it worked for you please consider accepting it.